# Jquery input event not working

Tags: jquery, events, input

I have the following Jquery code:

```
$("#search_query").on('input', ChangeMainSearchTerms);

function ChangeMainSearchTerms() {
  currentQuery = $('#search_query').val();
}
```

(`currentQuery` is a globally declared variable.)

And the following HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="query" id="search_query">
```

My problem is that ChangeMainSearchTerms is not being called when the input event occurs

I have tried changing the event to click and when I did this the ChangeMainSearchTerms function did run, this shows that the problem is something to do with the input event.

When the input event is detected Firefox outputs "ReferenceError: event is not defined" to the console. Chrome does not output a message but I still have the same problem

I googled this problem and found that some browsers require you to pass event as one of the arguments. However Jquery fixes this issue and I dont need to do this when i change the input event to a click event (remember I said that click events on this object work)

How do i fix this?

Comment: You have to pass explecitely `event` as handler parameter on FF: `function ChangeMainSearchTerms(event){}`. That's said, because you tell us it doesn't work on chrome either, provide minimalistic sample replicating your issue. e.g, what is `ChangeMainSearchTerms` code?

Comment: Its working fine on chrome 48.0v,http://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/MqM76/711/.

Comment: This is the code

function ChangeMainSearchTerms() {
        currentQuery = $('#search_query').val();
    }

currentQuery is a globally declared variable. Other functions which access this are able to do so successfully.

I dont think the content of this function is relevant because the code inside it itself does not run. It does not matter if i put console.log() or breakpoints in it.

Comment: @sam You mean, if you just set it as `function ChangeMainSearchTerms() { console.log('called!'); }` there is no output in console???  Silly question, but what about your browser cache?!

Comment: `event` is undefined in firefox, because firefox doesn't have this property and instead you can provides an event to an event handler function `ChangeMainSearchTerms` as a parameter.

However your code will work in Chrome and IE

Comment: The `event` object is not relevant here because you're not trying to use it. (jQuery would still pass it to your function as an argument, but you do *not* need to declare any arguments if you don't need to use them.)

Comment: @nnnnnn: Agreed. The question was edited later with javascript code. Though it seems a strange issue.